# Does liquid markup have an "each with index" equivalent?

Tags: iteration, liquid

I need to loop through an array of items, alternating between two different background colors as I go. Is there a way to do this in liquid markup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say `items` contains `["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]`, then something like this:

```
{% for item in items %}
  {{forloop.index | modulo: 2}} -> {{item}}
{% endfor %}
```

would produce:

```
1 -> a
0 -> b
1 -> c
0 -> d
1 -> e
```